# R lattice histogram add the mean as text to each histogram

Tags: r, histogram, lattice

According to the previous questions answered I thought the following script should work.

```
require(lattice)

histogram(cyl~mpg|gear*am,
        data=mtcars,
        nint=5,
        panel=function(y,...){
            panel.histogram(...)
            m<-mean(y)
            panel.txt(x=30,y=60,labels=m)
        }
)
```

The histograms plot but I'm getting the "packet 1 argument "y" is missing, with no default"

Help appreciated as I've wasted an hour of my life on this puzzle..

Comment: What value are you trying to print? A histogram plot is a univariate plot with no explicit `y` value (ie passing `cyl` here has no effect).

Answer (score 0):

`panel.histogram` needs an `x` argument (not a `y` argument) which is a clue that this is what `histogram` passes to the panel.

Also, you need to pass the `x` argument through to `panel.histogram` by including it in the argument list.

Finally, it's `panel.text` rather than `panel.txt`.

```
histogram(cyl~mpg|gear*am,
          data=mtcars,
          nint=5,
          panel=function(x, ...){
              panel.histogram(x=x,...)
              m<-mean(x)
              panel.text(x=30,y=60,labels=m)
          }
)
```

[image]